# How to generate p12 certificate with 100 years validity using flash builder

Tags: android, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am trying to upload debug version in google play store and i am getting this error

Upload failed

You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future.

I don't know how to extend the certificate validity to 100 years. I have seen in the forums to create certificate using keytool. But i am getting lot of errors. can any one help me is there any way directly i can create certificate with 100 years validity using flash builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Alexander. I need a certificate of 100 years validity so i found a solution that using command prompt we can do that.. I only missed that in win 7 we need to run command prompt as administrator then enter the following command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.p12 -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the Adobe article [Using Flash Builder 4.5 to package applications for Google Android devices](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html)?

[image]